# Android studio _ A lot of records in LogCat?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I am `selecting` from `sqlite` and then add in `ArrayList` my records is over 10000 .Then Loop on `ArrayList` for show in `LogCat` for review the records but in `LogCat` don't show all of data ? How I can show all of my records in `Logcat` or anywhere else ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < listCDM.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("MyLog",
            listCDM.get(i).getDate()
                    + "**" +
                    listCDM.get(i).getTime()
                    + "**" +
                    listCDM.get(i).getLat()
                    + "**" +
                    listCDM.get(i).getLng()
                    + "**" +
                    listCDM.get(i).getCounts() + "**" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because idea log cat buffer default size is 1024. You can change it
**android-studio\bin\idea.properties** is path, where you must change default size of buffer
**idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024**

read this configuration documentation
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration